# Why data received is different to sent by Electron event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, electron

I'm trying make CRUD operation in `Electron`, where using `MongoDB`, and `Mongoose` for `Electron` connect to database.

I have a function `list` for return the "return" of `Mongoose`. When I debugging return data, is show correct in my terminal

```
  ipc.on('products.list', function(event, query) {
    Service.list(query, function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);  // this will be print correct result
      event.sender.send('product.list', data);
    });
  });
```

Result of code upper part:

```
[ { _id: 55c15f2981260a6f0ef8a657,
    __v: 0,
    deleted_at: '',
    updated_at: '',
    created_at: Tue Aug 04 2015 21:51:52 GMT-0300 (BRT),
    measure: '',
    aplication: '',
    model: 'Mode XBA',
    reference: 'Reference test 123',
    code: '2028' } ]
```

But when I debug return data by client side with fallowing code, result is not correct and is not equal server side print.

Client side code:

```
ipc.on('product.list', function(data) {
    window.data = data;
    console.log(data); // this will print incorrect result
});
ipc.send('products.list', {});
```

Result of client side received:

```
{  
   "$__":{....},
   "_doc":{...},
   "_posts":{...},
   "_pres":{...},
   "isNew":false
}
```

Contains more objects in each element.

Why this happens? How to can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem!

This return is result from Mongoose

```
{  
   "$__":{....},
   "_doc":{...},
   "_posts":{...},
   "_pres":{...},
   "isNew":false
}
```

For return only property, is need add options `{lean : true}`

Ex:

```
Model.find(this.query)
  .lean()
  .exec(function(err, data) {}
);
```

More detail in [`Mongoose` Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)